# FFMPEG reports different (wrong) video resolution compared to how it actually plays

Tags: ffmpeg, rendering, video-capture, resolution

Quick question, i have a movie, which was cut and rendered with Sony Vegas from its original format to a .wmv file. Here comes the tricky part, movie when played, either with `VLC` or `WMP`, has a resolution of 656x480 ... BUT when i run a *ffmpeg -i* on it, it says it has a resolution of `600x480` ....

I took the time of actually capturing a frame and croping it with photoshop and its `656` and not `600` like ffmpeg its reporting, why would this could be happening? How could i fix the headers resolution? Would that have any impact on video re-rendering? As i said, VLC and WMP seems not to care about the incorrect headers and are playing it right, BUT, jwplayer seems to be using the header information, which i don't blame him, its correct to do that, but why the video headers could be wrong?

```
ffmpeg -i trailer.wmv
```

```
Input #0, asf, from 'trailer.wmv':
Duration: 00:01:04.93, start: 3.000000, bitrate: 2144 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, mono, 32 kb/s
Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3, yuv420p, 600x480 [PAR 59:54 DAR 295:216], 2065 kb/
s, 25.00 tb(r)
```

And yeah, the `PAR/DAR` parameters are also wrong, but honestly, i don't understand that technical shit, usually watch video and make sure it look good, any feedback would be appreciated :P

Is there a way to change the container information with ffmpeg so applications that actually do use the container information don't render video incorrectly?

Answer (score 17):

FFMPEG is 100% correct, that technical stuff is important :D

Your **PAR** (pixel aspect ratio) and **DAR** (display aspect ratio) are actually correct, and you proved it by capturing a screenshot and measuring.

What threw you off was the **PAR**. ***Not all pixels are square!*** IE: 1:1, although most downloaded videos will be so you probably never noticed. Some players such as VLC will recognize the PAR value and stretch the video accordingly to meet the **DAR**. DVD video is a great example of this.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio

So ffmpeg says your video width is 600. Multiply that by the **PAR** and you'll get "real" width. Meaning as if the pixels were square and not rectangular (horizontally).
600 * (59/54) = 656 (rounded) Number look familiar?

Now take the "real" size: 656 / 480 = 1.366 and look at your DAR: 295 / 216 = 1.366

Magic!

As you found out not all video players are smart enough to recognize the PAR and perform the appropriate stretching. You can change it to a 1:1 using ffmpeg easily using the setsar and scale video filters.

ffmpeg ...stuff... -vf "scale=656:480,setsar=1:1" ...more stuff...

For the curious, it's called setsar because it's also refered to as Sample (aka Pixel) Aspect Ratio: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#setsar-1

Hope this help, I'm sure it confuses many people (including myself) at first.